# Confused about why two Panels work differently

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have a problem that is really confusing me. Let me lay some background. I am trying to develop my own Editor Control. I wish to have a blinking caret, I know I can do this using CreateCaret, ShowCaret ect but this is not how I wish to do it, I wish to implement this myself.  My caret does not blink and I cant understand why.

The way I'm trying to implement this is by caching the area below the caret and then display the caret. Then half a second later I repaint the cached data back to the Editor Control therefore effecting a flashing caret. I have tried using just a Graphics Object and a Bitmap for the cache neither worked but I think I know why. So I decided to experiment. I set up one Panel on the Form itself through the Designer and one is handed coded into the Caret class itself. The Panel on the Form works but the Panel encapsulated within the class doesn't and I don't know why. My question is why?

Below is the Code. The BlinkTimer_Tick method just causes the Blink. Paint just Paints the caret, none of this should be hard to understand.

BackupBackground copies the area below the Caret to the cache, while RestoreBackground copies the cache to the Control. Now the problem is if you comment out the lines commented with "Works if this line is commented out" in both methods it all works but when these are not commented it doesn't work the caret does not blink. Both these Panels are set up the same.

```
    private void BlinkTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Paint();
        _BlinkTimer.Start();
    }

    private void BackupBackground(Graphics SrcGraph)
    {
        Form TF = _Parent.FindForm() as Form;
        Panel P = TF.Controls["_TestPanel"] as Panel;
        P = _Buffer; // Works if this line is Commentted out

        Graphics DestGraph = P.CreateGraphics();

        IntPtr SrcHDC = SrcGraph.GetHdc();
        IntPtr DestHDC = DestGraph.GetHdc();

        BitBlt(DestHDC, 0, 0, _Size.Width, _Size.Height,
               SrcHDC, _Location.X, _Location.Y, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);

        DestGraph.ReleaseHdc(DestHDC);
        SrcGraph.ReleaseHdc(SrcHDC);
    }

    private void RestoreBackground(Graphics DestGraph)
    {
        Form TF = _Parent.FindForm() as Form;
        Panel P = TF.Controls["_TestPanel"] as Panel;
        P = _Buffer; // Works if this line is Commentted out

        Graphics SrcGraph = P.CreateGraphics();

        IntPtr SrcHDC = SrcGraph.GetHdc();
        IntPtr DestHDC = DestGraph.GetHdc();

        BitBlt(DestHDC, _Location.X, _Location.Y, _Size.Width, _Size.Height,
               SrcHDC, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);

        DestGraph.ReleaseHdc(DestHDC);
        SrcGraph.ReleaseHdc(SrcHDC);
    }

    internal void Paint()
    {
        Graphics Graph = _Parent.CreateGraphics();
        if (!_BlinkOn)
        {
            // Restore Graphics from Backup
            RestoreBackground(Graph);

            _BlinkOn = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Backup Graphics
            Graph.Flush();
            BackupBackground(Graph);

            // Draw Caret
            using (SolidBrush P = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
            {
                Graph.FillRectangle(P, new Rectangle(_Location, _Size));
            }

            _BlinkOn = false;
        }
    }
```

The Caret should flash in both circumstances as I change nothing really but it only flashes when I use the Panel on the Form.

Note: I do not intend to use a Panel for the cache I was just experimenting and found this behavior and its weird, so I need to know.

Thanks Danny.

Comment: Get a book or follow a tutorial to learn how to draw on-screen in WinForms. Do not try to draw from a timer, always draw from the `Paint` event handler and use the event's `PaintEventArgs`. Do not call `CreateGraphics()`. Call `Invalidate` in your timer event or whatever to add the caret pixels to the pixels that will be updated. You have a long way to go.

Comment: @Dour High Arch You have clearly misunderstood. Invalidate won't work in this case that is why even the Windows API draws its caret outside the usual Paint system used for controls. Even when calling Invalidate there are no guarantee that the Paint will happen when you wish. The timing and efficiency are why you should not ever use the Paint event for this sort of thing. Its overkill and often unperdicatable.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which may reduces many descriptions and saves us from guessing the meaning of certain variables.

Comment: What's the `_Buffer`, do you mean `_Buffer = p`?

Comment: @Drake Wu Sorry for the late reply my dog had nine puppies last night. Posting more code is not possible at this time as the code is quite large and spread over a number of files. I can if you wish provide instructions on how to develop a Test App but it will need to be added as a separate question or possibly a non-answer to this one. _Buffer by the way is the encapsulated Panel.

Comment: @Dour High Arch Thinking about what you said on my drive to work, I could just Invalidate() the region containing the Caret and then call Update() to just draw the Caret. This would work and would be both efficient and predictable and may be the way I ultimately go, however it still does not answer why the Panels behave differently. Thanks for the thought.

Comment: I don't know what the real mistake is, but after new a panel and covering it with another one always gets something unexpected.

Comment: @Drake Wu - MSFT The _Buffer Panel is never displayed or parented to the Form so I don't now how they could interact with each other. The _Buffer has an access modifier of private so the Form doesn't even know it exists. Thanks